# How to execute a page object programme in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am basically trying to run a sample page object framework in java in Selenium .I have tried to run some sample classes given by some of the sites and forums. But for some reason, it doesnt seem to work. I dont know if I am missing out anything. Please help.  Thank You

I have tried these examples - 
https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/08/09/selenium-2web-driver-land-where-page-objects-are-king

http://www.wakaleo.com/blog/selenium-2-webdriver-quick-tips-page-object-navigation-strategies

```
    package google;

    import org.junit.After;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class WhenAUserSearchesOnGoogle {

private GoogleSearchPage page;

@Before
public void openTheBrowser() {
    page = PageFactory.initElements(new ChromeDriver(), GoogleSearchPage.class);
    page.open("http://google.co.nz/");
 }

@After
public void closeTheBrowser() {
    page.close();
}

@Test
public void whenTheUserSearchesForCatsTheResultPageTitleShouldContainCats() {
    page.searchFor("cats");
    //assertThat(page.getTitle(), containsString("cats") );
}   
    }
```

Above is the page factory class that I am using.

Following is the Page object.

```
    package google;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    //import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;



    public class GoogleSearchPage {

protected WebDriver driver;

private WebElement q;   

private WebElement btnG;

public GoogleSearchPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

public void open(String url) {
    driver.get(url);
}

public void close() {
    driver.quit();
}

public String getTitle() {
    return driver.getTitle();
}

public void searchFor(String searchTerm) {
    q.sendKeys(searchTerm);
    btnG.click();
}

public void typeSearchTerm(String searchTerm) {
    q.sendKeys(searchTerm);
}

public void clickOnSearch() {
    btnG.click();
}
    }
```

The stack trace says
FAILED: whenTheUserSearchesForCatsTheResultPageTitleShouldContainCats

Comment: this is very unspecific. please tell us what fails. is there a stack trace?

Comment: I have added the snippet that I am using.

Comment: where does ```g``` and ```btnG``` get initialized?

Comment: 'q' and 'btnG', they are the names of the text box and the search button respectively from the google home page, they are the web Elements used here

Comment: i was aware of that. see sircapsalots' answer for why I asked...

Answer (score 1):

Your WebElement's aren't being bound by any selectors, ergo the `PageFactory` is failing. (it doesn't know how to find these)

Add the `@FindBy` annotation before each web element. e.g

```
@FindBy(css = "[name='q']") public WebElement q;
@Findby(css = "[name='btnG]") public WebElement btnG;
```

You'll get red underlines underneath `@Findby`. Just do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to import it in.

Comment: Hey Jaydev, please put your entire stack trace in the post.  It's hard to decipher whats wrong if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Install the TestNG test framework to generate the report automatically